# Observables depending on each other

Tags: reactive-programming, rxjs

```
A:

    formSubmit ---- validate and map to errors >>> if errors, 
                   /                               display them and do other stuff
                  /
   formchange ---/

------------------------------

B:
                     pause if invalid
   formSubmit ----                      ---- transformData >>> submit
                   pause if in progress 

-----------------------------------

* ---: stream transformations
* >>>: subscription / observer
```

I have streams/observables as drawn in this diagram to handle a typical form submission in a web application.

Some points:

1) `B` relies on `A`: I don't want to submit if validations fail.

2) I want to validate on both `formSubmit` and `formChange`, that's why I merged them.

So far so good. But as far as I  understand, I have no control over which observable is handled first when they use the same source `formSubmit`. To have control over such thing would be against the philosophy of reactive programming?

How do I make `B` "wait" for result of `A`, which were ticked based on the same source `formSubmit`?

Or a better questions is, what would be the neatest way of handling this scenario in a reactive way?

Edit:

My current solution is to not merge `formSubmit` and `formChange`. Instead, I do validation on them separately.